# How we can create a Unique Id in Perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to create a **UniqueId**. Is there a function I can call, such that every time when I use that it will give me a new Id, always with a different value?

Comment: like when ever i will call that subroutine it will give me a Unique Id

Comment: cryptographic hash? Random number generator basically

Comment: what is that cryptographic hash ??

Comment: Perhaps it would help to know what you need this for?

Comment: @RedCricket he is not up to you , dont yell , but answer ..LOL

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The better way you can use this also

```
use UUID::Generator::PurePerl;

sub create_search_id {
    my $this =shift;
    my $args=shift;
    my $ug = UUID::Generator::PurePerl->new();
    my $uuid1 = $ug->generate_v1();
    return $uuid1;
}
```

From here you can learn about [UUID::Generator::PurePerl](http://search.cpan.org/~banb/UUID-Generator-PurePerl-0.04_02/lib/UUID/Generator/PurePerl.pm)

Comment: if i want to concatenate i can do in this function ??

Comment: yup in $uuid1 u can concatenate

Comment: What is the purpose of `$this` and `$args` in this code? If these variables are not used then no point to _manifest_ them.

Answer (score 28):

Use [Data::UUID](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Data-UUID-1.219/UUID.pm) to generate unique IDs:

```
use Data::UUID;

$ug    = Data::UUID->new;
$uuid1 = $ug->create();   # Or create_str()
```

Comment: Do $ug->to_string($uuid1); to get it as a string.

Comment: But please check https://github.com/rjbs/Data-UUID/issues/5 and other issues... and possibly decide for another UUID-generating module on CPAN.

Answer (score 10):

If you have some restriction on the modules you can use and you are running your script on Linux, you can use this workaround:

```
my $uuid = `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid`;
```

You don't need to install a new package on your system to use it.

Comment: Slightly more typing, but it's definitively faster to open & read the file with perl functions than using an external cat, e.g. `$uuid = do { open my $fh, "/proc/sys/kernel/random/uuid" or die $!; scalar <$fh> };`

Answer (score 7):

Probably worth noting that on Windows machines, you could also use Win32:

```
use Win32;    
my $guid = Win32::GuidGen();
```

Comment: ... which is included in a Perl installed on Windows.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative using [Data::GUID](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Data::GUID)

```
use Data::GUID;
my $guid = Data::GUID->new;
my $uniqueIdString = guid->as_string;
```

or

```
use Data::GUID;
my $uniqueIdString = Data::GUID->new->as_string;
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [Data::Uniqid](http://search.cpan.org/~mwx/Data-Uniqid/Uniqid.pm) , this module has 3 methods:

```
use Data::Uniqid qw ( suniqid uniqid luniqid );
$id = suniqid; #genrates a very short id valid only for the localhost and with a liftime of 1 day
$id = uniqid;  #generates a short id valid on the local host 
$id = luniqid; #generates a long id valid everywhere and ever
```

Answer (score 1):

I also really liked the idea to use the Linux OS tool `uuidgen` in this answer:
[Version 5 UUID in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17222428/version-5-uuid-in-perl#answer-17225422)

On my Debian Linux system I have it at `/usr/bin/uuidgen`

Answer (score 0):

Mix into `set` array the characters you want be in your `UUID`

```
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

say "Generate passwords\n";
say genPass(16) for (0..10);
say '';
say "Generate UUIDs\n";
say genUUID() for (0..10);

sub genPass {
    my $len = shift;
    my @set = ('A'..'Z','a'..'z',0..9,split('','~!@#$%^&*()_+{}[]-=;:<>?"\''));
    my $num = $#set;
    my $uuid;

    $uuid .= $set[rand($num)] while $len--;

    return $uuid;
}

sub genUUID {
    my $uuid;
    my @set = ('a'..'z',0..9);
    my $num = $#set;

    $uuid .= $set[rand($num)] for 1..8;
    $uuid .= '-';
    for (1..3) {
        $uuid .= $set[rand($num)] for 1..4;
        $uuid .= '-';
    }

    $uuid .= $set[rand($num)] for 1..12;

    return $uuid;
}
```

Sample of output

```
Generate passwords

yWXjV{{z0=6T-NVt
<ETH0(9IETcb[c!=
]cONV~*6PoTp1L~<
F8Ve>^u<Hymq]ZFd
<fdV(Z[~EUE?_Ufe
9A9y*iJ3Wta:jg*Y
7r2pP<1voI@x=cFe
Z7bZdha+U;:7aAeT
c2?a7S"mEpt%q43V
uC^q5]iPg~8E4CwJ
gwK+CBM?bnvgS@hg

Generate UUIDs

arrle2tc-x414-o8qi-i82f-obmwrbumlows
xmeg8ekk-ka2m-k4vo-l6xn-lor2s3z1lgn4
35d36bfr-jngc-6qiv-ubq8-nlysa2oaja12
m6yi4joo-1lpv-8obg-zjed-yesyqnq6rjxh
d3edwfbf-znwo-8s2o-4ld3-vntd20ps1fe5
twim8wr7-z0jj-0a20-uypt-sk80yubnaj8h
b4fkoodo-sp16-sa0h-2nlm-kicej06wlwn6
1r1rjy50-2wjo-620t-5ffn-5quw5qjztdfo
tr005kl0-k6yt-syz2-nrhq-k83ghybxjzm1
opxm1mjz-mvu8-feyf-if5o-411zayail60w
380v388j-acct-3zap-0nty-688b04eozrkx
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

[Firebase-style push id guid in Perl](https://gist.github.com/robdelacruz/25d1bc5a7ea72bd86088d2f28f2ba5f9)

It generates a guid in alphabetical order of the time it was generated. Useful if you want to sort record guids in the time order it was generated.