# Generate a unique Id in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl, and I need to generate a unique ID with 6 characters and only numbers, is there a way to do that simply?

I found :

```
use UUID::Generator::PurePerl;

sub create_search_id {
    my $this =shift;
    my $args=shift;
    my $ug = UUID::Generator::PurePerl->new();
    my $uuid1 = $ug->generate_v1();
    return $uuid1;
}
```

But the `use` statement generates an internal server error... Thanks !

Comment: What internal server error does it generate? You'll need to look in your log files because the specifics of internal server errors are not reported to clients.

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq1.html#What's-the-difference-between-%22perl%22-and-%22Perl%22%3f

Comment: You have installed the module `UUID::Generator::PurePerl`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How we can create a Unique Id in Perl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628244/how-we-can-create-a-unique-id-in-perl)

Comment: Does the error start with this: `Can't locate UUID/Generator/PurePerl.pm in @INC`? If so, do this: `perl -MCPAN -e 'install UUID::Generator::PurePerl'` at the command line. If not, and "Internal server error" is literally your error, we need more info, such as whether this is a web GUI, along with any error log entries surrounding the running of the code.

Comment: By `6 characters` do you mean `0` through `9` and `A` through `F` (i.e. hexadecimal) or do you mean only six digits?  If the latter (i.e. 6 digits), you only have a million unique numbers: I'd just start with `000000` then `000001` then ... until `999999` (which is where you have to stop) and if necessary save the number to a file and read it back in when you need the next one.

Answer (score 2):

A [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UUID) is a special form of unique identifier; any UUID-generating module is unlikely to support creating an identifier in the form you want.

I'm not certain what "6 characters and only numbers" means; if you mean 6 digits, just something like this:

```
my $id = join '', map int rand 10, 1..6;
```

But to make it unique, you'd need to be able to check that it isn't already in use, and you haven't told us anything about how you are using it.